# Duplicate custom item listview android

Tags: android

I tried to create chat applications. but I get an error on the nexus 5. listview while on other devices running normally.
I used the shape to the right and left positions. anyone can help? thanks.

```
adpChat = new SimpleAdapter(ChatPersonal.this, listChat, R.layout.list_personal_chat_detail,
            new String[]{ "MESSAGE","DATE","SENDRECEIVE","STSMSG","KEY","ATTNAME","ATTTEXT","SELECTED" },
            new int[]{R.id.col_message,R.id.col_date,R.id.col_SendReceive,R.id.col_stsMsg,R.id.col_key,R.id.col_AttName,R.id.col_AttText,R.id.col_selected }){
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            LinearLayout box_text = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.box_text);
            LinearLayout text_chat = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.text_chat);
            TextView col_date =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.col_date);
            TextView col_sts_msg =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.col_stsMsg);
            TextView send_recevie = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.col_SendReceive);
            ImageView iv_msg_check = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv_msg_check);
            TextView col_setected = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.col_selected);

            LinearLayout boxAttText = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.boxAttText);
            EmojiconTextView tvAttText = (EmojiconTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.col_AttText);

            if(!"".equals(tvAttText.getText().toString())){
                boxAttText.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }else{
                boxAttText.setVisibility(GONE);
            }

            if(!"0".equals(col_setected.getText().toString())){
                box_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#20000000"));
            }else{
                box_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
            }

            if("S".equals(send_recevie.getText().toString())){
                iv_msg_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if("D".equals(col_sts_msg.getText().toString())){
                    iv_msg_check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_msg_double_check_grey);
                }else if("P".equals(col_sts_msg.getText().toString())){
                    iv_msg_check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_msg_single_check_grey);
                }else{
                    col_sts_msg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
                }
                text_chat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_chat_send);
                box_text.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.CENTER);
                box_text.setPadding(80,0,20,0);
            }else if("R".equals(send_recevie.getText().toString())){
                iv_msg_check.setVisibility(GONE);
                if("0".equals(col_sts_msg.getText().toString())){
                    iv_msg_check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_receive_msg_unread);
                }else if("1".equals(col_sts_msg.getText().toString())){
                    iv_msg_check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_receive_msg_readed);
                }else{
                    col_sts_msg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
                }
                text_chat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_chat_receive);
                box_text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER);
                box_text.setPadding(20,0,80,0);
            }

            return v;
        }
    };
    lv_personal_chat.setAdapter(adpChat);
```

[this a screenshoot of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNqlY.jpg)

Comment: your code is not written with Java code convention rules. It is too hard to read.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in nexus 5 device?

Comment: I can not see the error report on the nexus 5, because I do not have these devices for the trial. I asked my friend to install the application on her phone. I did not find emulator nexus 5 with android version 6.0.1 for the trial, so I do not know what's wrong. I have tried the app on my android device versions 4.2.2 to 6.0.0 and runs well, but not at the nexus 5 android 6.0.1. Is it possible that my script above is not compatible?